# Несколько последовательных http запросов

Tags: android, http

Здравствуйте!

Моя программа берет данные с сервера, но так как сервер иногда глючит и лагает (с первого раза ответ не приходит), хочу сделать так что бы если ответ не пришел через 10 секунд посылался новый запрос, и так до тех пор пока не придет ответ или пока кол-во запросов не превысит 10. Пытался вставить `wait(10000)` в `asynctask` который делает запрос и парсит ответ, но тогда основной поток (UI) подвисает на это время. а хотелось бы что бы эти запросы и ожидания проходили в стороне.

вот здесь создается `asynctask`

```
WeatherGetter wg = new WeatherGetter();
    wg.execute(url);
    try {
        weather = wg.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (weatherSucces) {
        announceNewWeather(weather);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server unavalibale", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

а это сам asynctask

```
@Override
protected Weather doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jParser.getJSON(arg0[0]);

        try {
            JSONObject main = jsonObject.getJSONObject("main");
            temp = main.getInt("temp");
            humidity = main.getInt("humidity");
            pressure = main.getInt("pressure");
            tempMin = main.getInt("temp_min");
            tempMax = main.getInt("temp_max");

            JSONObject sys = jsonObject.getJSONObject("sys");
            sst = sys.getLong("sunset");
            srt = sys.getLong("sunrise");

            JSONObject wind = jsonObject.getJSONObject("wind");
            speed = wind.getDouble("speed");
            deg = wind.getInt("deg");

            JSONArray weather = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");
            for (int i = 0; i < weather.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject weatherObj = weather.getJSONObject(i);
                description = weatherObj.getString("description");
                id = weatherObj.getInt("id");
            }
            cod = jsonObject.getInt("cod");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (cod == 200) {
        GetWeatherService.weatherSucces = true;
    }
    mTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Weather currentWeather = new Weather(temp, tempMin, tempMax, id,
            humidity, speed, deg, pressure, description, mTime, srt, sst);

    return currentWeather;
}
```

Comment: `wg.execute(url);` - это запускается AsyncTask? Тогда, что это `weather = wg.get();`?

Comment: weather=wg.get(); - получаем результат работы asynctask, в данном случае объект содержащий данные о погоде

Comment: а уверены, что он уже успел отработать? а метод get будет ждать. (док: "Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result."). а ждать в главном треде... вот оно и висит. Вам нужно разделить код как бы на две части. Первая часть по клику на кнопке настривает AsyncTask и запускает. А в методе `onPostExecute` выполняете вторую половину работы - обновляете интерфейс.

Comment: А можно по-конкретнее, если не сложно? То есть get я убираю, но как тогда передать получившийся объект в сервис(запрос идет из сервиса)? И почему основной поток висит, сервис же вроде не в основном потоке исполняется?

Comment: я думаю, я все конкретно расписал. То, что запрос идет с таска - это хорошо, но get - блокирующая операция, поэтому, пока таск там себе работает, главный поток ждет. Формально получается однопоточное приложение.

По нажатию на кнопку "обновить" (или как там оно называется), нужно выполнить только 

    WeatherGetter wg = new WeatherGetter();
    wg.execute(url);

А вот концовку - в `onPostExecute`. Почитайте [это](http://habrahabr.ru/post/115127/).

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснения! я просто еще только разбираюсь, бывает трудно сразу въехать.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Привет  q3er,
начнём с того что не факт что сервер лагает как Вы говорили - если в секунду на сервер кроме вашего  пришло ещё 10000 запросов то он просто отвечает один за другим по очереди . Далее - если Вы думаете что 10 сек это  достаточно чтобы послать новый запрос тогда используйте лучше Thread - им управлять легче чем asyncTask . Вы не запустите второй asyncTask пока не закончится первый . То что первый закончился вам надо периодически проверять . Я спрашивал людей которые хорошо знают android - ни один мне не сказал что если Вы вызвали cancel для acyncTask - то  он вот взял и закрылся сразу - только Android знает когда его остановить .  Используйте простой Thread для решения своей задачи - он работает прекрасно в случаях подобных Вашему .  Я сам убедился в этом когда у меня возникали проблемы с asyncTask подобные Вашей .

Comment: > cancel для acyncTask - то он вот 

видимо нужно просто очень внимательно почитать документацию. Очень внимательно. Там сказано, что таск должен сам время от времени проверять, а не "закенселили ли его?" (метод `isCancelled()`). И если да, то принимать какие-то решения.

С потоками точно также.

> То что первый закончился вам надо периодически проверять .

ага, конечно. А `onPostExecute` для слабаков.

Comment: "только Android знает когда его остановить" - это прекрасно. -1